# converting json bool values to C# bool values

Tags: c#

I ma trying to convert json boolean value string to C# equivalent. This is my code:

```
  string jsonResponseString = "{boolvalue:'true'}";
  dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponseString);

  if (jsonResponse.boolvalue == true){
    Console.WriteLine("yes it is bool");
  }
  else{
    Console.WriteLine("no it is still a string");
  }
```

Unfortunately, boolvalue remains string `"true"` and not bool `true`. Since I will not know at runtime what kind of obkect string I am getting, I'd like to awoid explicit typecasting with `DeserializeObject<type>`.  I feel like I am missing something obvious. What is the correct way of converting string bools to actual bool values?

Comment: `if (jsonResponse.boolvalue == "true")` check the type, the value literally is a string, so your check needs to check the same type. If you actually check the value type, it's an `string`.

Comment: If you really can't know in advance, something like `bool b = jsonResponse switch { bool bb => bb, "true" => true, "false" => false, _ => throw new NoGoAwayThatsJustWrongException() }` would do. (While `Convert.ChangeType` is another option, I heartily discourage that because it will apply all sorts of exciting unexpected conversions. `bool.Parse` is an option but also one of those methods that does slightly more than is advertised on the tin.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The json value in your JSON string is literally the string `true`. For it to be parsed as a bool, you should declare it as a bool by removing the quotes:

```
string jsonResponseString = "{boolvalue: true}";
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using this just as an example. I reality, json came over the wire where it had no ' characters around bools. As it happened, I was commiting a typecast from dynamic to bool, and this caused the error (not shown in question). Thanks again, you gave me something to think about and look for problem elsewhere.