# WPF/C# With Newtonsoft have a condition (if / else) before rewriting .json (true / false value)

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I am a beginner and in a WPF application I need to rewrite an external json on only a few values. The values are only "true" and "false".
Like that :

```
{
  "option1": false,
  "option2": false,
  "option3": true,
}
```

I only use buttons, for example "activate", "deactivate"

Using NewtonSoft.Json I found this method, which works and modifies the json well, but I don't know how to make a condition so that if the value is already "true" then a Messagebox says "The value is already true".

```
 private void Activate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string myfile = "myfile.json";

            if (File.Exists(myfile))
            {
                string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(myfile);
                JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString) as JObject;
                JToken jToken = jObject.SelectToken("option1");
                jToken.Replace(true);
                string updatedJsonString = jObject.ToString();
                File.WriteAllText(myfile, updatedJsonString);
                MessageBox.Show("Option true");
            }
            else
            {
                MsgError();
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: I see `option1` in the json and `enableoption1` in the code. You sure those are correct?

Comment: Oops sorry, mistake in copying ^^

Comment: Just cast your jtoken to bool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting json bool values to C# bool values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196506/converting-json-bool-values-to-c-sharp-bool-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cast jToken to bool

```
    if((bool)jToken)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Option1 is true");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you ! Looks like it works fine if I write it like this.
`if ((bool)jToken is false)
{
// message
}`

But is this a good method?

Comment: Or you can write it like this (!(bool)jToken) or instead of "is" use == or != true.

Comment: But I always prefer this (!(bool)token)